# Installing Android emulator without eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, installation

How do I install an android emulator on a computer without eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to install eclipse for android emulator. Just download the android sdk and install it. You have to install JDK before installing android SDK. After completion of successful install. You will get two apps SDK manager and AVD Manager.

The SDK manager is used to update the SDK and to download the available libraries for different API versions and other libraries as you require.

The AVD manager is used to create android-virtual-devices for available API versions.

Open AVD manager from program files if you are using windows OS, it is very easy to create new AVD for any android API level available.

I hope it may help you.

Eclipse is just IDE to develop apps by using the installed SDK for android.

The "AVD Manager.exe" application can be found in the root SDK folder.

Answer (score 2):

The android eclipse plugin is simply sitting on top of the command-line tools which android provides for creating an emulator.

Once you have the android SDK on your machine, it provides these command-line tools.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html) article for details.