# Run AVD Emulator without Android Studio

Tags: android-virtual-device

is there a way to run the emulator without starting the Android Studio first. Perhaps from the command line. I know that this feature was available in older versions and has vanished since then. But perhaps someone found out how to do it anyways?

Comment: This is my main gripe about android development, the mainstream AOSP support for cli based DIY development with your own text editor is almost non existent... I'm comparing to Vue/React development, which is a world ahead.

Answer (score 340):

The way to run the emulator from the console (I assume that you installed it before, using Android Studio) is:

run

`cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin && ./avdmanager list avd`

**OR**

`cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools && ./emulator -list-avds`

You will get the list od your virtual installed devices. In my case it was:

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
  Name: Galaxy_Nexus_API_17
  Device: Galaxy Nexus (Google)
  Path: /home/piotr/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_17.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
  Based on: Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
  Skin: galaxy_nexus
  Sdcard: /home/piotr/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_17.avd/sdcard.img
```

Copy name of the device you want to run and then

`cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools && ./emulator -avd NAME_OF_YOUR_DEVICE`

in my case:

`cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools && ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_23`

Comment: Just a heads-up: For me the sdk was located in 
`/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: The last command gives me an error `bash: ./emulator: No such file or directory`. Any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: I think i was mistake using '|', you need to use '&&' instead. I'm not bash ninja. I edited answer

Comment: Depending on how installation of the SDK occurred, you _may_ have the environment variable `$ANDROID_HOME` set to the SDK location. 

`cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin && ./avdmanager list avd` and
`cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools && ./emulator -avd <NAME_OF_YOUR_DEVICE>`

Comment: @Dhyey got into the same issue. verify the path mentioned and try again. worked for me.

Comment: @PiotrGalas thank you so much. Finally after a long research your answer was very much helpful

Comment: Slightly Shorter command: `~/Library/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5` ... (no need for `cd` and `&& ./`) this way your current directory won't change

Comment: WINDOWS:
// see list of emulator devices
cd %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin && avdmanager.bat list avd

// run emulator
cd %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\ && emulator.exe -avd Pixel_2_API_23

Comment: Updating because the avdmanager is not necessary anymore. On Windows 10, you can run Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -list-avds to get the list.

Comment: emulator has been moved to the emulator folder in Android\Sdk. Executing it from there works.

Comment: Thanks your answer works, however it requires the cmd to be open for as long as I want the avd to stay open.. Is there a way to open the avd in a different process, so I could close down the cmd as soon as the avd launches?

Comment: @DanielB. I do not know :/

Comment: you can also get the avds directly from the emulator now: `./emulator -list-avds`

Comment: I had to use `-list-avds`

Comment: you can also use `cd ~/.android/avd/ && ls` to get your emulators, for each emulator, there is a .ini file and a .avd file, and the name before the .ini/.avd is the name of the emulator

Comment: [Windows] if you're getting `PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU`, change path from `...Sdk/tools` to `...Sdk/emulator`

Comment: This answer totally set me on the right path, but then I found that at the command-line I didn't have to change directories. I could just: `emulator -list-avds` and also run w/o need to cd with `emulator -avd <something_from_that_list>`

Answer (score 167):

**On MacOS**

First list down the installed emulators

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds
```

then run an emulator

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_27
```

Comment: Nice! Shortcut to run the first in the list: `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd $(~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds | head -n 1)`

Comment: This was very helpfull thanx @zeeawan .!

Comment: If someone gets: _"PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU."_. Try using: _"~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_27"_. **/emulator** instead of **/tools** is the tricky part.

Comment: @jnfran92, pick a coke anywhere and I'll come pay... Wonderful

Comment: it works for me on macOS 11.6, thank you @jnfran92

Comment: Works in Windows too, not the exact command obviously, but `emulator -list-avds` and `emulator -avd avd_name` in the `Android/sdk/emulator`  folder.

Comment: I got "qemu-system-aarch64': No such file or directory" when running this command.

Comment: This method will keep the shell active. Is there a way to launch it and let it run in the background so I can keep using the shell?

Answer (score 103):

You can make a batch file, that will open your emulator directly without opening Android Studio. If you are using Windows:

- Open Notepad
- New file
- Copy the next lines into your file:

  ```
   cd /d C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
   emulator @[YOUR_EMULATOR_DEVICE_NAME]
  ```

  Notes:
- Replace `[YOUR_EMULATOR_DEVICE_NAME]` with the device name you created in emulator
- To get the device name go to: `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools`
- Run `cmd` and type: `emulator -list-avds`
- Copy the device name and paste it in the batch file
- Save the file as `emulator.bat` and close
- Now double click on `emulator.bat` and you got the emulator running!

Comment: Windows also has %LOCALAPPDATA% as a variable, you could shorten that to:
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator @Pixel_2_API_27` (part after the @ is a device name, obtained from the mentioned `-list-avds`

Comment: Just typing `C:` is enough to change the drive. When I include the forward slash, ie `C:/`, I get an error in both Powershell and Command Prompt.

Comment: nice work. but if i close the command line, emulator too closes. can fix it or not?

Comment: It's not working for me the terminal opens and closes after double clicking

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil Newer versions of Android SDK have the following emulator path: `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator`.


So just replace the first line with `cd /d C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator`.

Comment: `cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools     emulator @Pixel_2_API_34` worked for me

Answer (score 44):

## Try this

**1. [Complete Video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBHQV7TgKgo) (For all windows versions)**

## OR

**2. Text tutorials**

- Open the command prompt and change the directory where your sdk is placed `D:\Softwares\Android\sdk\tools\bin>`
- now add your avdmanager in this,now your full code is `D:\Softwares\Android\sdk\tools\bin>avdmanager list avd`
- it will show you a list of emulator device that you have already created after few seconds
- now type`cd..`
- and run your emulator with this cmd, Here my emulator name is Tablet_API_25 so I have typed this name after the -avd.

  `D:\Softwares\Android\sdk\tools>emulator -avd Tablet_API_25`

**EDIT :** For Android Studio 3.2 or later, the path changes to `D:\Softwares\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator -avd Tablet_API_25`

i.e. `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\emulator -avd [AVD NAME]`

[image]

Comment: on my Windows 10 machine, "avdmanager list avd" command did not work; i used "emulator -list-avds" in the tools/ directory. In case this helps someone else :)

Comment: why i received error, [1020]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ..\emulator\lib64\qt\lib
Could not launch 'C:\Users\afaid\.android\avd\..\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe': No such file or directory

Comment: @HanWhiteking Have you tried to check the path you are specifying is correct or not ?

Comment: Emulators in recent versions have been moved out of the `tools` folder and are located in the `emulator` folder. For reference: `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`

Comment: Thanks this worked with slight changes. For me the android sdk was in C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/. Just go to C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/emulator and run `emulator.exe  -list-avds` to get device name. Then run `emulator.exe  -avd <device_name>`

Answer (score 41):

Open your terminal and

```
cd path_to/Android/Sdk/emulator
```

And run the following to get the emulator name that you created before using android studio

```
./emulator -list-avds
```

Replace $emulator_name with the one you want to launch and run

```
./emulator -avd $emulator_name
```

Comment: I used Mac os for doing the above, which platform do you use?

Comment: MacOS as well, I checked the $ANDROID_HOME path as wel, which is correct.

Comment: Navigate to path_to/Android/Sdk/emulator. You should have a file called emulator. If not you should create an emulator just for the first time from inside android studio. after that you can always open it the way mentioned above

Comment: My Windows path for Android 3.2 was C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator

Answer (score 38):

If you are starting emulator for Flutter applications, then you can run below command -

```
> flutter emulators --launch [Emulator ID]
```

In my case, emulator id is Pixel_2_API_29 as i created it with AVD manager in Android studio. so the command in my case is below -

```
> flutter emulators --launch Pixel_2_API_29
```

Thanks

Comment: the command to list emulators is `flutter emulators`

Answer (score 29):

In the ANDROID_HOME folder you will have tools folder

In Mac/Linux

`emulator -avd <avdName>`

In Windows

`emulator.exe -avd <avdName>`

If you are using `API 24` You can get the names of the emulator from the list

`android list avds`

If you are using `API 25` then you will get it with avdmanager in `tools\bin`

`avdmanager list avds`

Answer (score 22):

to list the emulators you have

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -list-avds
```

for example, I have this **Nexus_5X_API_24**

so the command to run that emulator is

```
cd ~/Library/Android/Sdk/tools && ./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_24
```

Comment: Yeah, the emulator binary has the `-list-avds` option. This is the easier way

Answer (score 21):

A Picture worth thousand words :)

How to Start AVD from MAC terminal

[image: AVD from MAC Terminal]

Comment: Working fine on ubuntu as well

Answer (score 21):

In **Ubuntu 20.04**, I found following solution

First You need to `export` Android path variables. For that :

```
export ANDROID_SDK=~/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
```

The paths may change according to your installation path. If **Android Studio** is installed using **Ubuntu Software** then path will be same as stated above.

If the `export` worked correctly, then following command should list your **AVD names**.

```
emulator -list-avds
```

In my case, I got the result

```
Nexus_5_API_30
```

Which is the name of my AVD.

If the above command have listed your **AVD name**, then you could run your AVD by :

```
emulator @YOUR_AVD_NAME
```

In my case

```
emulator @Nexus_5_API_30
```

You could add the `export` commands to `.bashrc` file to avoid typing `export`  command every time you needed to run **your AVD** .

Comment: Good to know that this works on Mac as well :) and I am using zsh.

Answer (score 15):

```
cd C:\Users\{computer_user_name}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
```

then run:

```
./emulator -list-avds
or
emulator -list-avds
```

output:

```
PIXEL_2_API_29
PIXEL_2_XL_API_29
```

then run:

```
./emulator -avd PIXEL_2_XL_API_29
or
emulator -avd PIXEL_2_XL_API_29
```

That's it

Comment: `C:\users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator -list-avds`

 output:       `Pixel_3a_API_30`
 then:          `C:\users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator -avd PIXEL_3a_API_30`

Answer (score 15):

### Mac-specific solution (applescript)

The applescript below will show a simple GUI which allows you to pick the android image you want to launch.

[image: Android emulator launcher GUI]

The script can be run from the terminal or from the ootb `script Editor.app` window > Run ▶.

You can convert the script to a standalone Mac app by selecting from **`script editor.app`** <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Export...</kbd> > <kbd>File Format: Application</kbd> > Save to `/Applications` folder.

```bash
### TODO! Set the correct path to your `emulator` command
set avds to paragraphs of (do shell script "~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds")
set avd to (choose from list avds with prompt "Please select an AVD to start" default items "None" OK button name {"Start"} cancel button name {"Cancel"})
do shell script "~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd " & avd & " -no-boot-anim > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

<sup>Note: To look up the correct path to the emulator run `which -a emulator` in a terminal.</sup>

In order to run the script from the terminal make it executable (e.g. `chmod +x android_launcher.sh`), and add the following shebang line at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
```

> NOTE: In more recent versions of the android sdk `--list-avds` includes an extra info line at the top, to remove it update the first from `...emulator -list-avds` to `...emulator -list-avds | tail -n +2`

Answer (score 12):

Here’s what you need to do:

**1**.[Download and extract the SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).
**2**.Open a terminal and navigate to the “tools” directory.
**3**.Launch the “android” tool (./android if you are currently in the tools directory).
**4**.Tick off the “SDK Platform” for each version of Android that you’d like to use in your emulator.
**5**.Click the “Install N Packages” button.
**6**.Click each package and tick off “Accept License” (legally, I’m probably required to tell you that this step may take several hours as you read each license ;).
**7**.Done with those licenses? Great. Click “Install”. Wait for the SDK manager to finish installing your packages, then you can close it.
**8**.Back in your terminal, still in the tools directory, enter ./android avd which will launch the Android Virtual Device Manager.
**9**.Click “New” and fill out the form to build the device you’d like to emulate. In the “Target” dropdown, you’ll see the SDK Platforms that you installed earlier. If the version you need is missing, you need to go back and install it. Click OK when you’re done.
**10**.Click on the device that you just created and click the “Start” button, tweak any options that you need on the Launch Options window, and click “Launch”.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097268/installing-android-emulator-without-eclipse) question's answer also.

Comment: The `android` tool is now deprecated

Answer (score 10):

Firstly change the directory where your avd devices are listed; for me it is here:

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools
```

Then run the emulator by following command:

*`./emulator -avd Your_avd_device_name`*

For me it is:

```
./emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_27
```

That's all.

Comment: Awesome.. so simple. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have installed Android studio properly,Open a command prompt and type 
    `emulator -list-avds`     which will display all the devices and then type `emulator @avd_name` where **avd_name** is the the name of your emulator installed.

Answer (score 9):

If you are on windows, what about a shortcut ? It is very easy to place whatever you want ant the icon is descriptive and nice.

- First, navigate to your android sdk, probably at `C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\`
- Then right click on emulator.exe and then click create shortcut.
- Your new and shiny shortcut gets created, probably with a predefined name.
- Right click on the shortcut, and on the target field (my computer is on spanish) add an extra parameter with the name of your device with an `@` in front (take a look at the picture below )

[image: shortcut params]

now you can do whatever yhou want with that shortcut, put on the desktop, bind it to the start-menu or whatever

Comment: Consider replacing the "@<device>" with "-avd <device>". For some reason, when using the "@", after closing the properties window and opening it again will not show the "@<device>" although it still works. when using the "-avd <device>" all the command stays there even if you close and reopen the properties window.

Comment: Well, I didn't used a windows laptop in a year, but if you provide me a newer screenshot I will update it. It will have to wait otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you've got Android Studio installed, and SDK in your PATH, it's:

`emulator -avd avd_name`

To get a list of AVD names, run:

`emulator -list-avds`

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

Answer (score 7):

> ```
>  Update 2020/05:
>  Windows 10
> ```

first get a list of emulators, **open cmd** and run :

```
cd %homepath%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
```

then

```
emulator -list-avds
```

next create a shortcut of `emulator.exe` found in the directory above, then change the properties in it by editing the `Target:` text box like this

`emulator.exe @YourDevice`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I already have the Studio installed. But without starting (not installing) the Android Studio you can directly start the emulator with

C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd YOUR_AVD_NAME

Answer (score 5):

The path for emulator is

```
/Users/<Username>/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/tools
```

Answer (score 5):

**For Linux/Ubuntu**

Create a new File from Terminal as

**gedit emulator.sh** (Use any Name for file here i have used "emulator")

now write following lines in this file

**cd /home/userName/Android/Sdk/tools/**

**./emulator @your created Android device Name**

(here after @ write the name of your AVD e.g

**./emulator @Nexus_5X_API_27**
)

Now save the file and run your emulator using following commands

**./emulator.sh**

In case of Permission denied use following command before above command

**chmod +x emulator.sh**

All set Go..

Comment: amazing and helped save my time so much

Comment: I tried following the above listed commands, but still not working.

Answer (score 5):

I am working with a React Native project and I also faced this problem

I solved it by making a **.bat** file in my desktop that I can open fast

The content of the **.bat** is

```
C:\Users\haria\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator\emulator -avd Pixel_2_XL_API_27
```

Where **haria** is my Windows username and
**Pixel_2_XL_API_27** is my emulator name

---

If you want to see your emulator name, open CMD (or PowerShell) and type (In Windows)

> cd C:\Users\haria\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator

Then to see the emulator(s) name

> ./emulator -list-avds

Answer (score 4):

Got it working for Windows 10:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools>emulator -list-avds
Nexus_5X_API_28
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_28
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the commands on Mac

```
cd ~/Library/Android/Sdk/tools/bin && ./avdmanager list avd
```

then

```
cd ~/Library/Android/Sdk/tools && ./emulator -avd NAME_OF_YOUR_DEVICE
```

Comment: Great for Mac users

Answer (score 4):

For Windows users:

- Copy your Emulator name.
- Go to this directory: `C:\Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`
- Right click on `emulator.exe` and send as a shortcut to where you want.
- Right click on shortcut .exe file and add your Emulator name just copied to end of target textbox with `@` symbol.
- Double click your shortcut and done!

`C:\Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe @EmulatorName`

Answer (score 4):

in 2019 , there might have some changes due to android studio update.

1. open command prompt [ cmd ]
2. change directory to sdk > tools

   cd C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools

if that address is not working 
    2.a open android studio
    2.b open Gradle Scripts directory ( if you have a open project inside android studio, you can easily find in left side of the screen. )
    2.c double click on local properties ( at the very bottom )
    2.d you should see the address right away, ( **sdk dir** )
    2.e change your directory to that address in command prompt ( like cd AppData )
    2.f change directory again to tools ( cd tools )

3. check the list of emulators that you all ready created by

   emulator -list-avds
4. copy your preferred emulator name.
5. choose and run your emulator by

   emulator -avd < your preferred emulator name >
6. done.

Comment: Just wanna point out that you can also create a desktop shortcut easily after that. Right click on desktop > new > shortcut and then paste in something like "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_6P_API_23"

Comment: Perfect solution! The best way to use the emulator in my opinion. In my case, there is an error **(PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU.)** occurring when I run `emulator -avd ...`, then, I managed to fix it by navigating to `...\Android\Sdk\emulator` instead of `\tools`

Answer (score 3):

1. Just create a .bat file. Call it smth like "run pixel 2.bat"
2. Open it with editor like Notepad++
3. Write 2 lines of code

```
cd C:\Users\mxsof\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator 
emulator -avd pixel_2_api_29
```

4. Launch it.

That's all. Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

this is how I've added a 'Start Pixel Emulator' to my start menu, and launched emulator in the same way as Android studio did:

[image]

this method can used to re-create any process launched by other process. let's start:

first I launched the emulator in the traditional way(from android studio)

[image]

and then I opened [procmanager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (from sysinternals) and used 'Find windows process (drag over window)' tool, and selected the emulator

[image]

this action brings up the specific process that is responsible for this windows window.

then I inspected the command that android studio used to open the emulator.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Android studio use this command to start the emulator:

```
C:\Software\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_6_API_33
```

let's create a new bat file with the exact same command

[image]

Then I used [this](https://www.easytechguides.com/pin-a-batch-file-to-the-taskbar-or-start-menu-in-windows-10/) guide to turn this script into a shortcut that can be attached to start menu.

for Dessert I wanted to also change the icon, so i used the icon of the emulator.exe file

[image]

[image]

now im starting the emulator in the same way android studio do it, but via a shortcut and without opening android studio.

Answer (score 3):

### Visual Studio Code - Flutter

if you are on visual studio code and using flutter, then you can simply launch it from there:

- press `ctrl`+`shift`+`p`
- type `Flutter: Launch Emulator`
- select an emulator to launch

  make sure you have already created an emulator in android studio.

Answer (score 2):

*(Only for **Windows**)*
Why to torture yourself? Make a **Simple BAT file** ! :

1. Open Notepad
2. Create the command as shown below
3. Save as *.bat
4. (Optional) Create a shortcut to that *.bat, rename shortcut and change icon

Here is the command:

> cd /d yourSdkPath\emulator && emulator -avd yourAVDName

Example:

> cd /d D:\Android_SDK\emulator && emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_28

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I've done to run the emulator quickly in windows :
I've created a windows batch file like this :

```
start C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -avd {Emulator_Name}
```

and just run the batch file every time I need the emulator.

Comment: the emulator has moved to the emulator directory, use C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe instead

Answer (score 1):

if you installed **Git** on your system. then you can run .sh bash code. I create the bash code for search from your created ADV Devices and list them. then you can select the number of adv device for run emulator without running Android studio.

link:
[adv-emulator.sh](https://gist.github.com/hamedtaheri32/61314a53aac5a1611e1df483757edfc5)

note [windows os]: please first add `%appdata%\..\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator` to your system Environment path, otherwise the bash-code not work.

Answer (score 1):

On windows

```
......\Android\sdk\tools\bin\avdmanager list avds

......\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5X_API_27
```

Comment: Brings up PANIC: Missing emulator engine program for 'x86' CPU. Although I can start it in Android Studio?

Comment: You can go to $ANDROID_HOME/emulator -avd DEVICE_NAME

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483370/android-emulator-error-message-panic-missing-emulator-engine-program-for-x86

Comment: @user668338 You should use `emulater.exe` found in `$ANDROID_HOME\emulator` folder, rather than the one found in `$ANDROID_HOME\tools`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows then create a .bat file and just double click that .bat file which will save you some time every day. Here is my code to launch android Emulator with use of batch file:

```
@echo off
title Android Emulator
color 1b
echo #################################

echo Please make sure that your android path is correct for the script
echo Change this path "C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator" to use your curret path and save it as a .bat file on your system to launch android emulator
echo #################################
c:
cd C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_28

pause
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows Users**

1. create and open a bat file(.bat is the extension of file)
2. Put the following code inside the file

   `cd /d  Path of SDK folder \emulator && emulator -avd Name of Emulator`

Here is the example

```
cd /d E:\Run\Android_Installation_Final\Sdk\emulator && emulator -avd Pixel_API_28
```

3. Save it.
4. Run it from any cmd(command prompt shell)

you can see my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994730/how-to-open-avd-amulator-when-windows-starts/54994731#54994731) to auto start emulator when windows start

Answer (score 1):

You may create a shell script and put it in your desktop:

```
Dim WinScriptHost
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator -avd <AVD_NAME>", 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Replace <user> with your user id, and <AVD_NAME> with the name of your avd file, e.g. pixel_2_api_28.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows**

In case anyone looking for shortcut / batch script - [Gist](https://gist.github.com/prachil007/3c8a45ca34308faafda1b41ef7d48216) - Download batch file.

```
@echo off
IF [%1]==[] (GOTO ExitWithPrompt)
set i=1
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('emulator -list-avds') DO (
    set /A i=i+1
    set em=%%i
    if %i% == %1 (
        echo Starting %em%
        emulator -avd %em%
        EXIT /B 0
    )
)
GOTO :Exit
:ExitWithPrompt
emulator -list-avds
echo Please enter the emulator number to start

:Exit
EXIT /B 0
```

Usage

```
D:\>start-emulator
Nexus_5_API_26
Please enter the emulator number to start

D:\>start-emulator 1
Starting Nexus_5_API_26
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
```

Comment: This lists me exactly 0 AVDs available.  How to install/download/seetup AVD from commandline?

Comment: @Tino I will share seperate gist for that by tomorrow EOD.

Answer (score 0):

Latest command as of 2024.

### Mac

List AVDs

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds
```

Run AVD

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_34_extension_level_7_x86_64
```