# How to run Android Virtual Device Manager from the terminal

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools, avd-manager

You might have already got my question from the title itself. To be more specific, I need to launch `Android Virtual Device Manager` [image: avd] without launching `Android Studio`. I know  how to start an emulator using my terminal. but that's not I want. I need to launch the "Manager" [image: avd] from terminal. Is it possible ?

**OS: Ubuntu 18.04**

[image]

Comment: I do not really know that much on Ubunu but you can try. Go to `$HOME/` I believe and to `Android\sdk`, there you should see `AVD Manager`. Try and launch from there. This is not a tested solution.

Comment: There's no program/dir called 'AVD Manager' under sdk folder. Before posting this question, I've tried avdmanager under `tools` dir. It's a `CLI` program. It has many options to list, start,stop and configure avds, except to launch the `GUI`. Anyway, tnx for the response ravi.

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718973/run-avd-emulator-without-android-studio

Comment: This should help too :)    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974568/how-do-i-launch-the-android-emulator-from-the-command-line

Answer (score -1):

```
emulator -avd <avdName>
```

avdName has to be replaced by your virtual device name.
To get avd names

```
emulator -list-avds
```