# How to open avd amulator when windows starts

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I work with AVD emulator and I have to restart my PC again and again because of some updates. so each time I start the pc, I have to run the custom bat file to start the emulator again and that becomes a tidy process to me.

Here is my [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718973/run-avd-emulator-without-android-studio/54994569#54994569) to make bat file to open emulator

I have searched on stackoverflow and on other places but couldn't find the exact solution.

Here are some relevant links

[Run AVD Emulator without Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718973/run-avd-emulator-without-android-studio/)

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Windows Users**

1. Make a shortcut of your bat file
2. Press Ctrl+R
3. Write `shell:startup` (it's a command to reach to startup folders) and press enter.
4. it will open a location in my case it is like "`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Startup`"
5. Paste your short cut here and on next start up your bat file will run automatically and will open the AVD emulator.