# Can i run my React-Native code in windows on android emulator without using android studio

Tags: react-native

My problem is that i want to run my react native code in windows on android emulator without using android studio.

i find many solution for that but anyone not working for me. Everyone say use your real device but i  want not use of real device.

please suggest me  any solution for that.

Comment: You can use your own mobile or Genymotion emulator

Answer (score 0):

Make a new notepad file
Content of that file-

```
cd /d C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
emulator -avd @YourEmulatorName
pause
```

Save the file as emulator.bat

Whenever you need to start the emulator double click on that file

If you need to know the name of your emulator-

```
cd /d C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools
emulator -avd -list-avds
```

Answer (score -2):

Install Bluestacks in your pc. Here is the link to download it : [Download Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/fr/index.html)

Comment: It is not the  solution for the given problem.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718973/run-avd-emulator-without-android-studio