# Android Studio Emulator : Unhandled exit 1d (Mac OS : Big Sur Beta)

Tags: android, macos, firebase, android-studio, android-emulator

I installed the latest Android Studio on my Macbook Air (late 2014, Big Sur BETA).
When I ran the emulator it gave me an `unhandled exit 1d` error. I have looked up all types of similar questions on Google/Stack Overflow/Youtube and I was not able to fix it.

Solutions that I have tried :

1. I reinstalled my AVD and SDK and HAXM, and invalidated the cache and restarted Studio, but that gave me the same error.
2. I made the file `~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini` and wrote :

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

This solution worked once but it crashes the next time I open the emulator or close and restart the emulator (I did not change anything meanwhile) and it gave me the same error as well.

3. I tried to open the emulator using:
   `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -gpu host -avd Pixel_2_API_28`
   which showed me the same error(on SDK 28, 29, and 30 as well).

Please help as I have an android class at my University and I need to make a project for it.

Comment: This answer helps me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718973/run-avd-emulator-without-android-studio

Answer (score 2):

This is the command that worked for me, on a MacBook Pro (2016) running a Big Sur Beta:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -gpu host -avd Pixel_3 -netdelay none -netspeed full
```

Once the emulator successfully started up, I was able to build the app directly from Android Studio and it launched properly on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Until having a permanent solution, start the emulator first by the below command then run the app

/Users/User_name/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd Tab_name -netdelay none -netspeed full

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got mine to work:

1. Download Android Studio Beta (or canary)
2. Open Android Studio Beta (or canary)
3. Open SDK Tools in Settings
4. Download latest emulator update
5. Run emulator using Terminal command below (add `--wipe-data` once and try again if it fails)

Command:
`~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -gpu host -avd "Pixel_2_API_30"` (or from your sdk path)

Note:
During my attempts I also updated Xcode to beta 12 with correct Command Line Tools. May or may not have made any difference but if you still got problems try it.

### It still fails (or great input lag)

1. Open any text editor and set `Vulkan = off GLDirectMem = on` as content
2. Save the file as `advancedFeatures.ini` and put it inside the folder `~/.android/`
3. Open Terminal, run `chmod 755 ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini`
4. Run `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -gpu host -avd "Pixel_3"` (or from your sdk path)
5. Click the three dots on the emulator toolbar, Go to Settings, Then Advanced tab, then under `OpenGL ES renderer` select `Desktop Native OpenGL`
6. Close the emulator settings
7. Quit the emulator
8. Start the emulator again (using the command)