# Android Command Line tools package path is null Windows

Tags: android, android-emulator

For our quality team, we want to install an API 30 version of the emulator so that technicians can test our applications without installing Android Studio.

I use the command line tools to download the different packages, but I find myself stuck when creating the emulator with this error

```
  Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:
null
```

Here are the packages I installed

```
      Installed packages:
  Path                                        | Version | Description
                     | Location
  -------                                     | ------- | -------
                     | -------
  build-tools;30.0.2                          | 30.0.2  | Android SDK Build-Tool
s 30.0.2             | build-tools\30.0.2\
  emulator                                    | 30.6.5  | Android Emulator
                     | emulator\
  patcher;v4                                  | 1       | SDK Patch Applier v4
                     | patcher\v4\
  platform-tools                              | 31.0.2  | Android SDK Platform-T
ools                 | platform-tools\
  platforms;android-30                        | 3       | Android SDK Platform 3
0                    | platforms\android-30\
  system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64 | 10      | Google APIs Intel x86
Atom_64 System Image | system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86_64\
```

Everything is installed in the bin folder of the command-line-tools folder

And the command I use to create an emulator

```
...\cmdline-tools\bin>avdmanager create avd -n "my_avd_30"
-k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64"
```

I don't know if this is causing the problem, but I have Android Studio installed on the PC
I have accepted all licenses

Did I miss a few things? forgot to install a package?

Thank for your help

Shindra

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718973/run-avd-emulator-without-android-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You must use the avdmanager present in the tools folder available when you download the build-tools.

By using it I manage to create an emulator and launch it using emulator.exe in the emulator folder at the root of the SDK folder given to SdK Manager